# Is this と quotative or conditional?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, conditionals, quotes

> 調べた会社は「ルールがなくなると、就職する会社を探す**ための**時間が長くなって、一生懸命勉強できなくなる**と**心配する学生もいます。...」と話しています。
>   The investigating company says "If they get rid of the rules then the time to find a company who is hiring will get longer and there will be students who worry *that* they can no longer study hard".

1) Is the と in bold quotative or conditional? I feel as though this could be translated in two ways:
a) There are students who will worry if/when they can't study hard.
b) There are students who will worry that they can't study hard.

2) Does ための add anything important here, or can I omit it without changing the meaning/nuance?

3) Not sure about 就職する in 就職する会社. I translated this as "companies who are hiring", but 就職する means "to find a job" not "to find an employee" so I think I might have got it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The と is quotative. You can parse the sentence in brackets as:

   > 『ルールがなくなると、就職する会社を探すための時間が長くなって、一生懸命勉強できなくなる。』と心配する学生もいます。

   The と in ルールがなくなると is conditional.

   Literally: There are students who worry / Some students worry (saying) "If the rules are abolished, the time to find a company to get a job in will get longer, and I won't be able to study hard."
2. Yes, 「就職する会社を探すための時間が長くなる」「就職する会社を探す時間が長くなる」 are both okay. I think the meaning will be clearer with ための.
3. 就職する会社 means "company (for me) to find a job in", 「(私が)就職する会社)」. The subject of 就職する is "I (i.e. 学生)".

Comment: That makes perfect sense but it never even occurred to me that the first two clauses would be part of the quote. Is there a grammatical reason why this must to be so? Same question about whether the second と can be conditional. I assumed it was a quote just because it seemed a nicer fit, but I couldn't see a grammatical reason for why it couldn't be a conditional here, and it still seemed to work with the context.

Comment: あ～・・　So you parsed it as 「ルールがなくなると、就職する会社を探すための時間が長くなります。」＋「一生懸命勉強できなくなると(=なったら)、心配する学生もいます。」... そういうふうに切ると、「心配する」の目的語/内容が、なくなっちゃうでしょう。「ん？何を心配するの？」ってなるし・・

Comment: In English I could say "If I don't get a job I'll worry". It doesn't need an explicit object. But if I understand correctly your saying that 就職しないと心配する (where と means 'if') would be incorrect? It's not clear to me why that should be.

Comment: "If I don't get a job I'll worry"「就職しないと/できないと(if)、心配になる。」っていうかな。。（でも「早く帰らないと(if)、親が心配する」て言うよね・・これは「親が私を心配する」の「私を」が含意されるのかな？）